# UIRefreshControl Custom Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

Help!!!
I am using `UIRefreshControl` for my iOS tableview pull-to-refresh feature.
However, my layout need to have a larger "loading area".
How can I make the area larger?? 
I have tried `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(500, 0, 0, 0)` but it does not work well when `refreshControl!.endRefreshing()` is called.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Refresh Control Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361002/ios-refresh-control-height)

Comment: This worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767876/uirefreshcontrol-with-low-height-uicollectionview